Parsing numeric data with thousands seperator in `polars`
I have a tsv file that contains integers with thousand separators. I'm trying to read it using polars==1.6.0, the encoding is utf-16
from io import BytesIO
import polars as pl

data = BytesIO(
"""
Id\tA\tB
1\t537\t2,288
2\t325\t1,047
3\t98\t194
""".encode("utf-16")
)

df = pl.read_csv(data, encoding="utf-16", separator="\t")
print(df)

I cannot figure out how to get polars to treat column "B" as integer rather than string, and I also cannot find a clean way of casting it to an integer.
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┐
│ Id     ┆ A   ┆ B     │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str   │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1      ┆ 537 ┆ 2,288 │
│ 2      ┆ 325 ┆ 1,047 │
│ 3      ┆ 98  ┆ 194   │
└────────┴─────┴───────┘

cast fails, as does passing the schema explicitly. I also tried using str.strip_chars and to remove the comma, my work-around is to use str.replace_all instead.
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("B").str.strip_chars(",").alias("B_strip_chars"),
    pl.col("B").str.replace_all("[^0-9]", "").alias("B_replace"),
)
print(df)

shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│ Id     ┆ A   ┆ B     ┆ B_strip_chars ┆ B_replace │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---           ┆ ---       │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str           ┆ str       │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 537 ┆ 2,288 ┆ 2,288         ┆ 2288      │
│ 2      ┆ 325 ┆ 1,047 ┆ 1,047         ┆ 1047      │
│ 3      ┆ 98  ┆ 194   ┆ 194           ┆ 194       │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────────────┴───────────┘

Also for this to work in general I'd need to ensure that read_csv doesn't try and infer types for any columns so I can convert them all manually (any numeric column with a value > 999 will contain a comma)

not sure if it's the best possible way, but simple .with_columns(pl.col.B.str.replace(",", "").cast(pl.Int32)) works

also pl.read_csv(..., use_pyarrow=True) works

I tried use_pyarrow and it didn't seem to work, at least when reading from an actual file - my toy example might not be 100% the same. I assumed replace would fail if there was more than 1 "," (i.e. 1,000,000) but I didn't try it.

To allow for possible multiple , separators use .str.replace_all:
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('B').str.replace_all(",", "").cast(pl.Int64))

which gives for the sample data:
   shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ Id  ┆ A   ┆ B    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 537 ┆ 2288 │
│ 2   ┆ 325 ┆ 1047 │
│ 3   ┆ 98  ┆ 194  │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘


To make this a more generic approach, instead of pl.col('B') you can do pl.col(pl.String) so it'll catch any column that came through as a string. You may need error handling on top of that but it's data dependent.

I'd probably want to apply to all columns from a list of columns if they're p.String though - otherwise it could strip comands from actual string fields?

I just noticed if I select all of the numeric columns (even those that have been inferred as string) it works, i.e. df = df.with_columns(pl.col('A', 'B').str.replace_all(",", "").cast(pl.Int64)) as well

If your source data is utf-16 (or anything besides utf-8) then polars is going to convert it to utf-8 through python. Since it needs to have that happen anyway, it might be better to do that conversion yourself and replace the ","s in the middle so that the native polars csv reader parses the data as numbers in the read_csv upfront rather than in a subsequent step
data.seek(0)
pl.read_csv(data.read().decode('utf-16').replace(',','').encode('utf-8'), separator="\t")

Just to emphasize that if your source data is already utf-8 then having python do the replace is almost certainly slower than @user19077881's answer. Only do this if your source isn't utf-8 because polars will convert it to utf-8 in python anyway. Of course, if you have columns that are actually supposed to be strings with commas then this doesn't work because it doesn't know the difference.
